# Как добавить фильтр в поиск?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

есть парсер случайного url изображения из гугл, но иногда возникает ошибка 'IndexError', потому что некоторые ссылки не оканчиваются на .png .jpg . jpeg. Так вот, как добавить фильтр, чтобы выводили только те url которые оканчиваются на .png .jpg .jpeg?

вот код:

```
import requests
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

r = s.get('https://www.google.ru/search?q=мем&tbm=isch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

elems = soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'rg_meta notranslate'})
print(loads(choice(elems).text)['ou'])
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не знаю почему, но `Google` не всегда возвращает теги с классом `rg_meta`, с этим и связана Ваша ошибка. Формат ссылок тут ни при чём.

Comment: Спасибо, а не знаете как это возможно исправить? Возможно использовать Яндекс или что-то другое?